# Read float values from file using readFloat()

Tags: android, file-io, readfile

I am trying to read float values from a txt file but I always get the value 0. I write the values on the file using writeFloat() and read using readFloat(). If I read on the computer (e.g. Matlab) I get the correct values but not if I read on my code, where I get 0 as the read value. What's wrong on my code?

I added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions and the path of the file is correct.

Write Values

```
try{
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(filename,true));
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        dos.writeFloat(value[i]);
    dos.close();
  }
catch(Exception e){;}
```

Read values

```
String strFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp/Values.txt";


try
{
  FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(strFilePath:);

   DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fin);

    float f;
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        f = dis.readFloat();
        Log.d("TAG", "float " + Float.toString(f));
    }

     dis.close();
   }
catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
{
  Log.d("ERROR", "FileNotFoundException : " + fe);
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
  Log.d("ERROR","IOException : " + ioe);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the content of the file that's written on the sdcard?

Comment: Just checked your code and it works. Maybe something is wrong with the initialization of the value array? Can you add that code?

Comment: Thanks for the question, your code works fine, so it helps me :)